# The "yarn-service" type of LLAP has stuck in accepted state

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn

The application llap0 name with the type of "yarn-service" has stuck in the accepted state and won't running therefore the HiveServer2 Interactive could not start.
When I want to start the application by:

```
$ yarn app -start llap0
```

I got the following error:

**ERROR client.ApiServiceClient: File does not exist: hdfs://NameNode-Host:8020/user/root/.yarn/services/llap0/llap0.json**

how can I change the state of "yarn-service" to running?

my cluster (HDP 3.1.4) config is:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 40960
yarn.scheduler.minimum.allocation-mb = 4096
yarn.scheduler.maximum.allocation-mb = 40960
hive.tez.container.size = 4096
num_llap_nodes_for_llap_daemons = 4
num_llap_nodes = 4 hive.llap.daemon.num.executors = 8
hive.server2.tez.sessions.per.default.queue = 1
hive.llap.daemon.yarn.container.mb = 36864 
llap_headroom_space = 2048
llap_heap_size = 30720 hive.llap.io.memory.size = 0
tez.am.resource.memory.mb = 4096
hive.heapsize = 30720
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restrar the ResourceManager and NodeManager manually on hosts:
in Apache Ambari Go to **Hosts** on each Host in the Components section click on the menu for **ResourceManager** and **NodeManager** and Select Restart.